# how to fill NA with mean only for 2 or less consequective values of NA

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am new to python. please help me how I should proceed.
The following dataframe contains large blocks of NaNs.  # Fill the NAs with mean only for 2 or less consecutive values of NAs.  # Refer to the documentation of fillna() to find out the parameter you would use to fill only a certail number of NAs. # The resulting dataframe should look like df_filled

```
# The resulting dataframe should look like df_filled shown below.

df = pd.DataFrame({'val1':[4,np.nan,7,np.nan,np.nan,9,5, np.nan , 1,9,np.nan, np.nan,np.nan, 5, np.nan], 
                    'val2': [ np.nan, 5,7,np.nan, np.nan,8,3,np.nan, 4,np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,np.nan,21,np.nan]})

d = {'val1': {0: 4.0,1: 5.7142857142857144,2: 7.0,3: 5.7142857142857144,4: np.nan,5: 9.0,6: 5.0,7: np.nan,8: 1.0,9: 9.0,10: np.nan,11: np.nan,12: np.nan,13: 5.0,14: np.nan},
'val2': {0: 8.0,1: 5.0,2: 7.0,3: 8.0,4: np.nan,5: 8.0,6: 3.0,7: np.nan,8: 4.0,9: np.nan,10: np.nan,11: np.nan,12: np.nan,13: 21.0,14: np.nan}}

df_filled = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: Did you experience any difficulties with this part: `Refer to the documentation of fillna() to find out the parameter you would use to fill only a certail number of NAs.`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this

```
df["val1"] = df["val1"].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean(), limit=2))
df["val2"] = df["val2"].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean(), limit=2))
print df
```

*Don't forget to let us know if it solved your problem :)*

Comment: thanks I got the answer using df.fillna(df.mean(),limit=2)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider loop over each dict series value and store information of **sum of all values different than NA**, **count of elements different than NA** and **array of indices with less or equal 2 consecutives NA values**.

Example:

```
'val1':[4,np.nan,7,np.nan,np.nan,9,5, np.nan , 1,9,np.nan, np.nan,np.nan, 5, np.nan]

 sum = 40,
 count = 7,
 array_na = [1, 3, 4, 7, 10, 11, 14]
```

In my logic case, 12 indice won't be filled with mean since it's a third np.nan value. Also, I don't think this is the logic that you mentioned since the description it's quite confusing and result seems to be wrong:

```
{'val1': {0: 4.0,1: 5.7142857142857144,2: 7.0,3: 5.7142857142857144,4: np.nan,5: 9.0,6: 5.0,7: np.nan,8: 1.0,9: 9.0,10: np.nan,11: np.nan,12: np.nan,13: 5.0,14: np.nan}
```