# Fill Consecutive NaNs in Pandas Series

Tags: pandas, nan, series, fillna

I want to fill missing values in my pandas series, if there are less than 3 consecutive NANs.

**Original series with missing values:**

```
s=pd.Series(pd.np.random.randn(20))
s[[1,3,5,7,12,13,14,15, 18]]=pd.np.nan
```

Gives:

```
0     0.444025
1          NaN
2     0.631753
3          NaN
4    -0.577121
5          NaN
6     1.299953
7          NaN
8    -0.252173
9     0.287641
10    0.941953
11   -1.624728
12         NaN
13         NaN
14         NaN
15         NaN
16    0.998952
17    0.195698
18         NaN
19   -0.788995
```

BUT, using pandas.fillna() with a limit only fills the # of values specified (not number of CONSECUTIVE NANs, as expected):

```
s.fillna(value=0, limit=3) #Fails to fill values at position 7 and forward
```

Desired output would fill NANs with 0 at positions 1,3,5,7, and 18. It would leave series of 4 NaNs in place in position 12-15.

The documentation and other posts on SO have not resolved this issue (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45372816/how-to-fill-na-with-mean-only-for-2-or-less-consequective-values-of-na)). Documentation seems to imply that this limit will work on consecutive NANs, not the overall # in entire dataset that will be filled. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the solutions. I am just surprised there is not a simpler way to do this!

Comment: Would it be simpler to use "shift"? i.e., first store the location of all long NAN gaps with `long_nan_gaps= s.index[s.shift(1).isnull() & s.shift(-1).isnull() & s.isnull()]`, then fill ALL NANs with 0, and then restore the saved locations to NAN after the fact? I appreciate the many solutions; just wondering if one you have proposed below is better than what I had figured out here for myself (that I thought was too ugly/ confusing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We start with finding where the `nan` values are via `pd.Series.notna`.

As we use `cumsum`, whenever we encounter a non-null value, we increment the cumulative sum this generating convenient groups for contiguous `nan` values.

However, for all but the first group (and maybe the first group) we begin with a non-null value.  So, I take the negation of `mask` and sum the total number of null values within each group.

Now I `fillna` and use `pd.DataFrame.where` to mask the spots where the sum of `nan` values was too much.

```
mask = s.notna()
c_na = (~mask).groupby(mask.cumsum()).transform('sum')
filled = s.fillna(0).where(c_na.le(3))
s.fillna(filled)

0     1.418895
1     0.000000
2    -0.553732
3     0.000000
4    -0.101532
5     0.000000
6    -1.334803
7     0.000000
8     1.159115
9     0.309093
10   -0.047970
11    0.051567
12         NaN
13         NaN
14         NaN
15         NaN
16    0.623673
17   -0.786857
18    0.000000
19    0.310688
dtype: float64
```

---

Here is a fancy Numpy/Pandas way using `np.bincount` and `pd.factorize`

```
v = s.values
m = np.isnan(v)
f, u = pd.factorize((~m).cumsum())
filled = np.where(
    ~m, v,
    np.where(np.bincount(f, weights=mask)[f] <= 3, 0, np.nan)
)

pd.Series(filled, s.index)

0     1.418895
1     0.000000
2    -0.553732
3     0.000000
4    -0.101532
5     0.000000
6    -1.334803
7     0.000000
8     1.159115
9     0.309093
10   -0.047970
11    0.051567
12         NaN
13         NaN
14         NaN
15         NaN
16    0.623673
17   -0.786857
18    0.000000
19    0.310688
dtype: float64
```

Comment: You can save one `fillna` with `masked = s.groupby(m.cumsum()).transform('size').gt(3); s.fillna(0).mask(masked)`

Comment: I think should be  s.fillna(0).mask(sumna.ge(3)), right ?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on what the code is doint? I see it works but don't understand exactly what's going on in the `groupby`

Comment: Just got to a computer.  I'll elaborate in a few minutes

Comment: @piRSquared, no worries, I'm about to leave mine, will look tomorrow. Cheers!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ `size` will capture the first non-null plus subsequent nulls and will typically be one more than the number of nulls.  Mind you, we are after the number of nulls per group.  `'count'` would do better, or the inverse rather.  Working on this now (-:

Answer (score 2):

First, build a na cum_count column. Consecutive nas will have same cum_count.

```
df = s.to_frame('value').assign(na_ct=s.notna().cumsum())
```

Then we can group by the na cum_count, check the number of rows in each group and decide weather to fill the nas or not.

```
df.groupby(df.na_ct).apply(lambda x: x if len(x)>4 else x.fillna(0)).value
Out[76]: 
0     0.195634
1     0.000000
2    -0.818349
3     0.000000
4    -2.347686
5     0.000000
6    -0.464040
7     0.000000
8     0.179321
9     0.356661
10    0.471832
11   -1.217082
12         NaN
13         NaN
14         NaN
15         NaN
16   -0.112744
17   -2.630191
18    0.000000
19   -0.313592
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this ?

```
t=s[s.isnull()];
v=pd.Series(t.index,index=t.index).diff().ne(1).cumsum();
z=v[v.isin(v.value_counts()[v.value_counts().gt(3)].index.values)];
s.fillna(0).mask(s.index.isin(z.index))
Out[348]: 
0    -0.781728
1     0.000000
2    -1.114552
3     0.000000
4     1.242452
5     0.000000
6     0.599486
7     0.000000
8     0.757384
9    -1.559661
10    0.527451
11   -0.426890
12         NaN
13         NaN
14         NaN
15         NaN
16   -1.264962
17    0.703790
18    0.000000
19    0.953616
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with `rolling` operator in the following fashion:

1) Create a function that returns 0 only if there are less than X values in a window

```
fillnaiflessthan(series, count):
    if series.isnull().sum() < count and series.center == pd.NaN:
         return 0
```

2) Then use it inside `rolling`

```
s.rolling(window=5, center=True, min_periods=0).apply(lambda x: fillnaiflessthan(x, 4))
```